# Extract keys from yaml file using awk

Tags: awk

Let's say I have a yaml file like this one:

```
foo:
  bar: 1

env:
  firstVar: true
  secondVar: 20
  aa_thirdVar: 'hello'
  aa_fourthVar: false
```

and I need to get the keys under the `env` key except for the keys with `aa_` prefix as a bash array in order to use the array in a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `yq` command from the https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ a proper tool to parse the YAML format files, you could do:

```
yq -r '.env|to_entries[]|
    if (.key|test("^[^a][^a][^_]*$")) then
        ( .key + "=" + (.value | @sh) )
    else
        empty
    end
' infile
```

which outputs:

```
firstVar=true
secondVar=20
```

now you only need to `export` these sets of variables

```
export $(yq ... )
```

or create an array:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(yq ... ) )
```

---

In the `( .key + "=" + (.value | @sh) )` part, it concatenates the pairs of the key-value that those are produced by using the `to_entries` function and the `@sh` syntax (which is known as the "Format String and Escaping") is used to provide the POSIX sh shell escape formatting on *values*.

Comment: At least in jq-1.6 there's a `startswith()` boolean, so you could also do something like `.env | to_entries[] | select(.key | startswith("aa_") | not) | ( .key + "=" + (.value | @sh) )`

Comment: @steeldriver I didn't think they could have several functions for that aside match(), capture() and test(); interesting! thanks a lot

Comment: tbh I only figured that out just before you posted - but I hadn't come up with anything as nice as your `( .key + "=" + (.value | @sh) )` for the output formatting